# C# writing to log file

Tags: c#

I want to write some events and exceptions to a log file when my app is running. The log file size is limited to N Megabytes. When the file size is more than N Megabytes, I want to overwrite from the start of the file. Since the file size is N megabytes I don't want to copy to temporary file and then rename it.

Give any suggestions/approach for the above problem.

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? there are tons of apps (like NLog) that do this for you.

Comment: you also have log4net, it's really customizable, and as said before, don't reinvent the wheel :) (I think log4net will be better than anything you could do, unless you spent 12 month on it, but your boss won't like it).

Comment: Windows or Web? if Web **Elmah** rocks! http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question refers to the .Net trace listener which writes .svclog files then the answer is no: you cannot configure it to start writing from the beginning when it reaches a certain limit.

However, Microsoft have a [solution called Circular Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395205.aspx) that you can try to circumvent the problem of log files growing without limit.

Answer (score 2):

Try Log4Not , or Enterprise Library logging component by Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

Either use Log4net (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) where you can do this

```
    logger.Debug("Here is a debug log.");
    logger.Info("... and an Info log.");
    logger.Warn("... and a warning.");
    logger.Error("... and an error.");
    logger.Fatal("... and a fatal error.");
```

or use the Enterprise Libaries (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) where you can do this

```
    LogEntry entry = new LogEntry()
                         {
                             Message = "Hello Ent. Lib. Logging"
                         };
    Logger.Write(entry);
```

Both can be configured to point to a file thru the web/app.config.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) !
It is really flexible and allows you to change the behaviour of logging at run-time (where to log / how to log / what to log ...).

The [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#RollingFileAppender) allows you to define the behaviour when a given size-limit is reached, and it could probably answer your question.

Comment: I think the [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html) would do a better job ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
float N = 1; //Log File size in MB
FileInfo logFile = new FileInfo("c:\\myLogFile.txt");
if (logFile.Length > 1024 * N)
{
   logFile.Delete();
   logFile.Create();
}

using (StreamWriter logStream = logFile.AppendText())
   logStream.Write("String to write");
```

the simpliest way, and probably the worst.
Edited to reflect  Hans Kesting comments.

Comment: It would be less bad if you used `new FileInfo(filename).Length`, instead of reading every byte.

Comment: In fact, I was searching for something like FileInfo.GetSize or Fileinfo.Size and didn't found anything.
Testing for files size is not a thing that happens frequently in my filed.
BTW, another way to improve the snippet above si to use a Using statement on the StreamWriter

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to Log4Net I can recommend [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) 
We find it more transparent and easy to use after own simple log class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try enterprise logging library from Microsoft which will give you many more features than the older FileIO operations or the log4net.

Microsoft has released 5.0 version of enterprise library, which will help you write logs and also configuring them easily with a UI, give it a try.